# Windows 7 Desktop View

Tags: windows-7, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the multiple desktop utility you suggest for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1498/what-is-the-multiple-desktop-utility-you-suggest-for-windows)

Is there any software in Windows 7 that lets you organize your desktop or view?

In my friend's Macintosh he has a program that lets him organize his view. For example the first view is just for copying files then he could create a second view for listening to music, a third view for his office work. All views are running but only one view is shown at a time and he could shift to another view if he wanted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need a "virtual desktop manager".

LifeHacker made recently [a selection of the 5 most-used](http://lifehacker.com/5358291/five-best-virtual+desktop-managers) across its readers, for all OSes.

[**Dexpot**](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?id=home), one of the 5 selected, is quite renowned as a virtual desktop manager for Windows. [This blog entry](http://www.enduserblog.com/2009/03/easiest-hack-ever-add-virtual-desktops-to-windows-with-dexpot-14.html) confirms it runs with Windows 7.

[image]